# Установить ограничение на вывод записей в foreach?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как сделать ограничение на вывод записей (например выводить только 3 записи) в `php`, когда используется `foreach`? Ниже представлю сам код:

```
    <?php
    $featured_posts = get_field('imtg_posts');
    if( $featured_posts ): ?>
        <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
            $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post->ID );
            $title = get_the_title( $featured_post->ID );
            $custom_field = get_field( 'field_name', $featured_post->ID );
            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $featured_post->ID );
            ?>
              <a class="s-services-button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>">READ MORE</a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы можете сделать свой счетчик итераций

```
<?php
$featured_posts = get_field('imtg_posts');
if( $featured_posts ): ?>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
        if ( $i > 2 ) {
            break;
        }

        $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $featured_post->ID );
        $custom_field = get_field( 'field_name', $featured_post->ID );
        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $featured_post->ID );
        ?>
          <a class="s-services-button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>">READ MORE</a>
    <?php
    $i++; 
endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```